How to delete one value from a key having multiple values in a collection of MongoDB
I have a collection:
{
    "_id" : {
    "portName" : "xe-xsa/3",
        "uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000d",
        "routerId" : "3.3.3.3"
    },
    "version" : NumberLong(4),
    "freeValues" : [],
    "occupiedResources" : {
        "21" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        },
        "22" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        },
        "23" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        },
        "24" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        },
        "25" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        },
        "26" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        },
        "27" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        },
        "28" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        },
        "29" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        },
        "30" : {
            "applicationName" : "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms"
        }
    },
    "_class" : "com.sdn.manage.resource.objectmodel.VlanPool"
}

From above collection I need to remove value "23": { applicationName: 'srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms' } from Key occupiedResources so I used the command below using the Mongo shell:
db.vlanPool.update(
    {
        $and: [{ "occupiedResources.21": { "applicationName": "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms" } },
            { "_id.routerId": "3.3.3.3" }, { "_id.portName": "xe-xsa/3" }]
    },
    {
        $pull: { "occupiedResources.23": { "applicationName": "srvcful-l2packet-manager-ms" } }
    }
)

But it gives the error:
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 2,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"
    }
})

Can someone find any error in my command or suggest how to pull one value out of multiple values from a key? Please advise.

This question is similar to: How to remove a field completely from a MongoDB document?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You have to use $unset to remove from object.

The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.

Here's how you can do it :-
db.vlanPool.update(
  {
    "_id.portName": "xe-xsa/3",
    "_id.uuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000d",  // filter if required
    "_id.routerId": "3.3.3.3"
  },
  {
    $unset: { "occupiedResources.23": "" }
  }
)

